# class with No Name(Empty name) is added in Area/Identity/Data folder ,when add identity using scaffolding identity in project using .net 8.0 and VS22?

Tags: .net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

I am created a new .Net core web application using vs 2022 and .NET 8.0 Framework. Project created successfully but when i try to add Asp.net core identity using scaffolding identity. I add dbcontext name and 'MyApplicationUser' in  User Class section ,then click on Add button.
DBcontext class file is added successfully in Area/Identity/Data folder but a class with no name(User Class) is added in this folder.I think the problem is in code-Generator.

Thanks

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTCl4.jpg)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFch4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found a direct solution, I figured out a workaround that achieves the same result.

1. During project creation when asked for `Authentication Type` change it from `None` to `Individual Accounts` [image: Authentication_Type_UI]
2. Make a file for the `ApplicationUser` file, and make it inherit from `IdentityUser` (This file can be put anywhere within the project, I put it in the `Data` Folder with the `ApplicationDbContext`) [image: ApplicationUser_Folder_Structure]

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ScaffoldFixExample.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

3. In the `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file, change the following line from

   `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext`

   to

   `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`
4. In the `Program.cs` file, change the following line from

   `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)`

   to

   `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)`
5. In the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in `/Views/Shared`, change the beginning from

```cshtml
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

to

```cshtml
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using ScaffoldFixExample.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Note: Replace `ScaffoldFixExample` with your projects/solutions name you set during creation (root folder name)

6. Create a new scaffold identity as you would normally - Right click project/root folder - `Add` - `New Scaffold Item` - `Identity`
7. Select which files you want (or click `Override all files`)
8. Set `DbContextClass` to `ApplicationDbContext`
9. Click `Add`

[image: Identity Example]

10. Once complete, open up the `Package Manager Console` - `View` -> `Other Windows` -> `Package Manager Console`
11. Run `update-database`
12. Once update database has finished, simply run the application and it should work properly (ASP.NET should still work, along with having support for register/login with the custom ApplicationUser)

Now the custom `ApplicationUser` is all setup, and can be used as you normally would.

---

Note: This does result in a slightly different folder structure than the method that is commonly used/used in the question.

To make it look/be structured the same do the following,

1. Move the `Migrations` folder into the root folder
2. Move the `Data` folder into the `/Area/Identity/` folder.
3. Update the `using` in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` from `@using <Project>.Data` to `@using <Project>.Areas.Identity.Data`
4. Add in the `@using <Project>.Areas.Identity.Data` in the file `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_ManageNav.cshtml`

#### Before

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]